# wrapAll Как оборачивать группами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день уважаемые. Такой вопрос как оборачивать li с class="item" в теги li class="item_group" ul class="ul_group" ...  по 3 штуки. (Если размер экрана браузера <768) Если количество элементов li нацело не делится на 3. То остаток тоже заворачивается в эти теги. Вот пример

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var item = $("item"),
    fullItems = $("item").length;

  if ($(body).width() < 768) {



  }

}
```

```css
.item_group {
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.ul_group {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="full">
  <li class="item">item1</li>
  <li class="item">item2</li>
  <li class="item">item3</li>
  <li class="item">item4</li>
  <li class="item">item5</li>
  <li class="item">item6</li>
  <li class="item">item7</li>
  <li class="item">item8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а какая цель группирования?

Comment: Там из этих сгруппированых элементов делается слайдер по 3 li. А если разрешения экрана будет <480px то мне уже надо оборачивать каждые 2-а элемента.

Comment: а какой слайдер используется?

Comment: Самописный. Когда у .full задано position:relative; height:200px; width:100%; overflow:hidden; А у li class="item_group" будет задано  position: absolute; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; а left будет меняться. Но это всё не важно